# В чем ошибка? - Qt, C++, ошибка доступа к private члену

Tags: c++, qt

Вот мой код:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <main/MainMenu>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    MainMenu m(a);
    w.setMenuBar(&m);
    return a.exec();
}
```

MainMenu - это мой класс:

```
class MainMenu{
public:
    MainMenu(QApplication app,QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QMenuBar(parent){
        QMenu *pm_file = new QMenu("&Меню");
        pm_file->addAction("&Выйти", &app, SLOT(quit()),Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_F4);
        this->addMenu(pm_file);
    }
};
```

Но при попытке компиляции, я получаю ошибку `C2248: QApplication::QApplication: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "QApplication"` в строке `MainMenu m(a);`. То есть, как я понимаю, я не могу получить доступ к конструктору QApplication, хотя тут он ведь и не нужен... В чем может быть ошибка? Вообще, я хочу установить соединение в своем классе со слотом `quit()`, может есть другой путь для этого?

Comment: Вы передаете QApplication по значению и хотите, что бы он скопировался (это явно не то, что Вам нужно). Передавайте по ссылке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QApplication` можно вообще не передавать. К нему можно получить доступ из любого места вашей программы, используя макрос `qApp`. Он определён в `qcoreapplication.h`:

```
#define qApp QCoreApplication::instance()
```

Тогда ваш код можно упростить следующим образом:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

class MainMenu : public QMenuBar
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainMenu(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QMenuBar(parent)
    {
        QMenu *pm_file = new QMenu("&Меню");
        pm_file->addAction("&Выйти", qApp, SLOT(quit()), Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_F4);
        this->addMenu(pm_file);
    }
};
```

Comment: спасибо, так действительно лучше. А зачем вы используете explicit? Погуглил, но конкретной пользы не понял.

Comment: @Nik, использование `explicit` чаще всего - вопрос предпочтения каждого отдельно взятого человека. Лично я использую его всегда, кроме тех случаев, когда я точно знаю, что вызов конструктора с одним аргументом будет абсолютно прозрачен, удобен и нагляден без использования названия класса.

Comment: Ну а в чем вообще польза от explicit?

Comment: Вот вам два класса: `class A { public: A(int); };` и `class B { public: explicit B(int); };`. Эти строки компилятор пропустит: `A a1 = A(0); A a2 = 0;`, будут сконструированы два равнозначных объекта, а вот здесь: `B b1 = B(0); B b2 = 0;` компилятор скажет, что при конструировании объекта `b2` неявно вызвать конструктор не получается. Это и есть эффект ключевого слова `explicit`.

Comment: Аа, понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш класс `MainMenu` - наверно должен унаследовать от `QMenuBar`?

```
class MainMenu : public QMenuBar
{
Q_OBJECT // добавьте чтоб использовать слоты и сигналы
public:
    // ...
};
```

Ну и как сказанно в комментах, `QApplication` надо передавать по ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!